# How can I get a line break in the "date" command on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, geektool

Is it possible to force a line break in the result of `date` command for Mac OS X?

This is intended to use with GeekTool so I can have the current date in the first line, and time in the second.

For now, I'm using two separate commands. The first one for date:

```
date '+%A %B %d, %Y'
```

And the second for time:

```
date '+%l:%M %p'
```

I tried to insert \n and CR, but without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `\n`, but `%n` works – see [`man strftime`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html).

```
date '+%A %B %d, %Y%n%l:%M %p'
```

Will output:

```
Sunday July 28, 2013
 2:18 PM
```

(Note that the initial whitespace on the second line is caused by the padded format.)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot slhck for the answer and the reference.